# How can I format this date? 2013-02-13T19:25:27.1381035-06:00

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, milliseconds

I am getting a feed that looks like this: `2013-02-13T19:25:27.1381035-06:00`

And I am setting it to an NSDate like this:

`NSDate *endDate = [tempFormatter1 dateFromString:myEndDateString]`

Can I use something like this:

`[tempFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss'SSS Z'"];`

Is it possible to convert it from this format?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to me it's already formatted.

Comment: ([Here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) is the formatter pattern reference.  You have the first part of the formatter pattern right, but it goes awry after "ss".)

Comment: (@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssSSSSSZZZZZ" -- I guess the first part wasn't right either.)

Comment: (And don't forget to set the locale to "en_US_POSIX".)

Comment: Thanks!  It works perfect, I just had to ad a `.` here: `ss.SSSSS`
So it ended up being this: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZZZZ`